# How can I export message filters from roundcube?

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, filtering, sieve

We are migrating from roundcube to GSuite (Google Apps). Many of our users have set up complex filters in their roundcube account. We would like to migrate these filters to their new GSuite accounts. I cannot find out how to export the filters from roundcube. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering in roundcube is provided by sieve. Per default, the sieve config files should be in `~/sieve`. They might also be in the maildir. If you cannot find it in either location, try searching for files with the `.sieve` extension.

Comment: Thanks. The sieve files were actually under `/var/vmail/mydomain.com/<username>/sieve`. Unfortunately, it looks like the format of roundcube and that of gmail are incompatible. I don't know if it is possible to translate between the two, but since you answered my initial question, I'll award you the answer.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg you could try this script and just reverse it: https://github.com/tomrittervg/gmail-to-sieve

Comment: Nice. This is a good start. Not sure if this is something I want to take on myself though.